# how to know signal strength without connection from router through wifi?

Tags: network-programming

If I have a mobile entered in WiFi network, how to know the single strength between a device and a router without getting connected.

Comment: Question is a bit vague. The WiFi hardware can give you a list of available hotspots and their signal strength.

Comment: Even if that hotspots didn't connected to WiFi hardware?

Comment: You can use several Wifi Analyzers. Just Google them and you'll be able to analyze the signal strength from certain points.